# Is it correct to use schemas of components for query parameter in OpenAPI 3.0?

Tags: swagger, openapi

OpenAPI 'components' section has 'schemas' and 'parameters'.

https://swagger.io/docs/specification/components/#structure

It looks like I can write the query parameter either way.
But is it correct to write the query parameter using the 'schemas' section?

Using the schemas section seems to be convenient as it can be reused for responses, etc.

```yaml
paths:
  /user:
    get:
      summary: Get User
      operationId: get-user
      description: ''
      parameters:
        - schema:
            $ref: '#/components/schemas/User'
          in: query
          name: schemas_user
          required: true
        - $ref: '#/components/parameters/QueryUser'
      responses:
        '200':
          description: OK
components:
  schemas:
    User:
      title: User
      type: string
      description: user in model
  parameters:
    QueryUser:
      name: query_user
      in: query
      required: true
      schema:
        type: string
      description: user in query
```

'schemas' is very expressive and can also represent objects.

However, objects cannot be used as query strings.

Does OpenAPI recommend the use of schemas for query strings?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, looks fine referring a schema from #components/schemas.
Please refer below snap that confirms the same. PS: you can try out pasting your Swagger JSON on editor.swagger.io
[image]

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  I know I can use schemas, but I would like to know if I should use it or not. schemas is very expressive and can also represent objects.
However, objects cannot be used as query strings.
Does OpenAPI recommend the use of schemas for query strings?

Comment: Hey, considering your doubt, IMO the OpenAPI being so robust, allows you to refer it from /components/schemas. But representing objects as a query parameter doesn't make much sense in the general REST world itself, thus you might consider accomodating the object in the request body instead. So better represent arrays for normal datatypes or only normal datatype for query parameters either by $ref or inline definition.